# How can I efficiently make a significant number of simultaneous Ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am executing 15 Ajax GET requests to fetch 15 different B64 images from S3. I am looking for an efficient way to simultaneously execute these requests. Is is best just to execute all of them within a `when(...)` call?

Comment: What kind of "efficiency" are you looking for? Do you have an actual problem?

Comment: I want it to not take 20 seconds to load them all ;) @Bergi

Comment: Well yes, just starting them from a loop will do the fetching in parallel. (As far as the browser/server allow simultaneous connections)

Comment: when() function is the way to go. As when will allow you to process 20 request simultaneously.

Comment: The answer is "It depends"

Comment: Write a php script that uses [multi_curl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) to retrieve all the files. Make one ajax call to this script passing all needed info, wait for the response. That's how I would do it anyway.